# Transform XML document changing encoding

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, encoding, utf-8

I have following code:

```
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
XsltArgumentList arguments = new XsltArgumentList();

string txId = SPOZUS_T2S_COMMON.Spozus.GetUniqueInputId;
arguments.AddParam("Id", string.Empty, txId);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in args)
{
    arguments.AddParam(kvp.Key, string.Empty, kvp.Value);
}
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xslt))
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
    {
            transform.Load(reader); // load transformation
    }
}

XDocument inDoc = new XDocument(_ecpIn.Message); // input document
XDocument outDoc = new XDocument(); // output document

using (XmlReader reader = inDoc.CreateReader())
{
    XmlWriter XWriter = outDoc.CreateWriter();
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(XWriter, transform.OutputSettings))
    {
        transform.Transform(reader, arguments, writer); // do the transformation
    }
}
```

I have the source document inDoc in utf-8 and I need to replace accentuated chars in the values of text value elements and get rid of those that does not match this pattern ([0-9a-zA-Z-\?:().,'+ ]([0-9a-zA-Z-\?:().,'+ ]*(/[0-9a-zA-Z-\?:().,'+ ])?)*).
Any idea?

Comment: So you are just going to remove characters from the document? It seems like this would change the meaning of the data.

Comment: No I would like to replace accentuated characters with their unaccented versions and replace all other characters not defined in the pattern with space.

Comment: This will change the meaning of the data. You should work to make the recipient of the data handle utf-8.

Comment: You can try to persuade SWIFT and Eurosystem to throw away their backward system compatibility policy. :-) There is no possibility to change this requirement.

Comment: Do SWIFT and Eurosystem support [windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or a different extended ascii character set?

Comment: ([0-9a-zA-Z-\?:().,'+ ]([0-9a-zA-Z-\?:().,'+ ](/[0-9a-zA-Z-\?:().,'+ ])?)) is the pattern they use in their validation xsd schema, so that is the only accepted format for this type of data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a XML with a Specific Encoding using XSLT and XMLWRITER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717121/how-to-create-a-xml-with-a-specific-encoding-using-xslt-and-xmlwriter)